# Interpretation of Phase Portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have the following system $x'=f(X)$ of ODES:
\begin{align}
x_1'=& -4x_1^3(x_2-2)^2 \\
x_2'=& 2x_1^4(2-x_2)
\end{align}

Solving for equilibria: I got $1$ at $(0, 2)$. I plotted this and I am curious about the strange behavior around the line $y=2$ (it looks like tiny oscillations). There is definitely saddle behaviour everywhere else. What does this mean:

Is there in fact only one equilibrium?

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: Sage interface to Maxima. `sage: maxima('plotdf([-4*x^3*(y-2)^2, 2*x^4*(2-y)],[x,y],[x,-10,10],[y,-10,10])')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving for the critical points, we find the only CP is $(0,2)$.

However, look at what happens to the system at those points individually:

- At $x_1 = 0$, what happens to the system, regardless of $x_2$?
- At $x_2 = 2$, what happens to the system, regardless of $x_1$?

This is what you are seeing in the strange looking phase portrait as the vertical line $x_1 = 0$ or the horizontal line $x_2 = 0$ make the system zero, regardless of the other value (that is, for all other values, the system is $x'_1 = x'_2 = 0$).

We can see these behaviors in the strange looking phase portrait, but you need to pick out the observations above. We have:

[image]

Comment: I think you could answer this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452592/using-bendixson-dulac-to-show-no-cyle-exists-for-system without a problem :)

Comment: Looks like your "phase-portrait"-drawing software got a work-out today!

Comment: @amWhy: Indeed! I need to get another variant! :-)

Comment: @Amzoti How does this explain the oscillations near the line y=2 in the diagram provided by the OP?