# Using Bendixson-Dulac to show no cyle exists for system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system $x'=f(x)$:
\begin{align}
x_1'=& 1+x_1x_2 \\
x_2'=& 2x_1^2+x_1^2x_2^2
\end{align}

I want to show there is no cycle (maybe I am wrong)

Maybe I am using the wrong theorem, but I plugged in a general $\alpha(x,y)$. To try to find $div(\alpha f)$ such that $div(\alpha f)$ is always less than or greater than zero. However, I didn't really get anywhere.

How can I find out of there is a cycle?

Comment: Probably w.r.t to the origin

Comment: Are you sure the system is written correctly (it is ugly if so)?

Comment: What I was asking is are they asking for only $x \gt 0, y \gt 0$? Have you dropped the problem?

Comment: I was just going off of the Bendixson-Dulac Theorem.

Comment: Finding a suitable Dulac function is just like finding a Lyapunov function. There is no known way to construct them, so it is a hard problem. When problems are difficult, you might get lucky by guessing, but this is generally not solvable. However, it is nice to have all sorts of things in our toolbox that we might be able to throw at a problem and I tried all sorts of tricks!

Comment: Bendixson-Poincaré-Dulac-Lyapunov seems to only complicate things here. Note that $x'_2\geqslant0$ everywhere hence any cycle must be included in some line $x_2=c$, which can only happen if $x'_2=0$ uniformly on the cycle, that is, $x_1=0$ uniformly on the cycle, but then $x'_1=1$ hence $x_1$ cannot constant, and we reached a contradiction.

Comment: I can't say that I fully understand why periodic orbit should be included in some line $x_2 = c$... However, your observation is cool and really allows to rule out periodic orbits :) but I'd rather use it this way: if $x_2 (t)$ were periodic, it will have a point at which $\dot{x}_2 = 0$. This can only happen when this periodic orbit crosses $x_1 = 0$. But it's not hard to show that there could be no periodic orbit crossing $x_1 = 0$. Another contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

My calculations show that you can take $\alpha(x_1, x_2)$ equal to $x_2$ and apply Bendixson-Dulac to $\alpha\cdot f$.

**EDIT** So, with a remark from topic starter I have to reformulate my answer. As it is proved below, it can be shown that this system has no closed trajectories that cross $x_1=0$ axis. Trajectories that go around origin are also excluded. Take bounded domain $D$ which boundary is hypothetical closed trajectory. It's not hard to construct simply-connected domain $G$ that contains closure of $D$ and that doesn't contain origin. You can use the offered function to apply Bendixson-Dulac for domain $G$ and get a contradiction. So, this shows that this system has no closed trajectories at all.

As for your second question... Suppose you know where are located all equilibria states and suppose you have two closed simple smooth (or piecewise smooth) curves $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ with following properties: (1) one of the curves lies inside the bounded part of plain which boundary is another curve, (2) tangent vectors along curves are transversal to the vector field (it's called "curves without contact"), (3) no equilibria states in the annulus between $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$. The 4th condition would be: vector field points "into" the annulus or "out" of it simultaneously on both curves. These conditions may help you to find out that there is a limit cycle in the annulus. That's because the limit cycles and equilibria states are the only possible examples of $\alpha$- and $\omega$-sets in bounded domains at plane.

Comment: If you use $alpha = x_2$ you only get that it is $\geq 0$ not strictly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's my fault, this $\alpha$ doesn't work how it thought to be. But with additional observations it works pretty well. We can prove that there could be no closed trajectories around the origin. If you look at vector field along $x_1=0$, you could figure that it points "right". There is no closed trajectory around $(0,0)$ because it must cross $x_1 = 0$ at least multiple times; but any trajectory that begins at $x_1 = 0$ goes to the right halfplane $x_1 > 0$ and never go to left halfplane (because of the direction of vector field along $x_1 = 0$). All other cases are due to Dulac.

Comment: @Evgeny For a shortcut, see comment on main.