# How to show the existence of heteroclinic orbits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

How can I show the existence of heteroclinic (or homoclinic, or even both) orbit given a system of differential equations? In specific my system is the following,

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{{d}r(\lambda)}{{d}\lambda}\right)^{2} 
= E^{2}-\left( 1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\frac{L^{2}}{r^{2}}-2K\, \left( 1-\frac{2M}{r}\right) \, ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{{d}\phi(\lambda)}{{d}\lambda}
= \frac{L}{r^{2}} \, ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{{d}t(\lambda)}{{d}\lambda} =
\frac{E}{\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)} \, ,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\theta(\lambda) = \frac{\pi}{2} \, .
\end{equation}

with $E, K, L, M \in \mathbb{R}$. Any references is welcome too!

Comment: Looking at the way that this system written (as is), it's very unlikely that it will have any of them in regular sense. You are probably interested in (hetero|homo)clinic orbits to equilibria or limit cycles. But there is no such states in finite part of the phase space (I'm taking $r \neq 0$ and $r \neq 2M$ as a phase space). For example, the second equation $\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda}$ is never zero in the finite part of the phase space, hence no equilibria or limit cycles. Probably some change of variables will transform this system to another one, which can in principle have such motions.

Comment: @Evgeny: Could you explain why $d\phi/d\lambda$ never zero implies that there are no limit cycles? Don't we also have to consider the other two degrees of freedom (from which one is also never zero)?

Comment: @MrYouMath Sure. Basically, it's the application of Rolle's theorem. Suppose that you have a $\Lambda$-periodic solution. In that case $\phi(0) = \phi(\Lambda)$ due to periodicity of solution which by Rolle's theorem implies that there must be a $\hat{\lambda}$ where $\frac{d\phi}{d\lambda} (\hat{\lambda}) = 0$. But from the right hand side of the system we see that in any finite part of the phase space this derivative is never zero. I could have applied this trick to $\frac{dt}{d\lambda}$ also. I credit this idea to Did, see comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452592/87697 .

Comment: @Evgeny: Thank you :). That is really a nice trick.

Comment: Can you confirm whether my guess was right or not? It's very interesting question for me.

Comment: @Evgeny Your guess was in the right sense, I've made a change of variables, namely, $u(r) = r^{-1}$ and, this way, I could get a better system to analyse, now I'm focused in find the equilibrium solution(s) of the system!

Comment: @Evgeny I think this reasoning would be more suitable when applied to $r$, because the angular velocity $\phi'$ is not suppose to be zero in a periodic orbit, but the radial velocity is supposed to be zero.

Comment: I've meant periodic orbit in a sense of "a closed trajectory in the original phase space'. If there is an additional interpretation of phase variables which allows different meaning, my observation is not useful then :)

Comment: If there is a different context for this system, can you add it to your question? For example, if $\phi \in \mathbb{S}^1$, not in $\mathbb{R}$, then closed orbits of this phase space correspond to $r(0) = r(\Lambda), \; t(0) = t(\Lambda), \; \phi(0) - \phi(\Lambda) = 2\pi k$, and that changes analysis a lot.